# How do I use generics with custom types?

Tags: go

I'm really confused about how the rules around generics work. I just want to have a function accept multiple custom types and have different logic for each one.

```
type myObjOne struct {
    myfield        string
}

type myObjTwo struct {
    myObjTwo
    myOtherField   string
}

type Generic interface {
    myObjOne | myObjTwo
}

func derp[T Generic](c T) {
    switch any(c).(type) {
    case myObjOne:
        // I can't access the fields of my types like this
        c.myfield = "sdfsfsdfdsf"
    case myObjTwo:
        c.myOtherField = "sdfsfsdfdsf"
    }
    return
}
```

Why is `c.myfield` throwing `c.myfield undefined (type T has no field or method myfield) compilerMissingFieldOrMethod`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`c` is type `T`, not the result of the type assertion.  Fix by assigning the result of the type assertion to a variable.

```
func derp[T Generic](c T) {
    switch c := any(c).(type) {
    case myObjOne:
        // I can't access the fields of my types like this
        c.myfield = "sdfsfsdfdsf"
    case myObjTwo:
        c.myOtherField = "sdfsfsdfdsf"
    }
    return
}
```

This code declares a second variable `c` in the type switch.  The type of `c` depends on the branch of the switch.

Comment: Is there also a way to just cast c to either myObjOne or myObjTwo so I can use it outside of the case statement?

Comment: Yes, you can use `c1, ok := any(c).myObjOne` where `c1` has type `myObjOne` for the remainder of the current block.   Go does not have casting.